# Django i want to breaks when data exists

Tags: python, django

When I add new years in harvest from `YearSet` but when year exists It doesn't break if statement.
I try to use `exists()` but it failed.

`models.py`

```
class YearSet(models.Model):
    year = models.CharField(max_length=4, default='')
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-year"]
class Harvest(models.Model):
    User_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='')
    product = models.IntegerField(default='')
    years = models.ForeignKey(YearSet, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='2017')
    Plant_id = models.ForeignKey(Plant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`view.py`

```
def CreateHarvest(request, Plant_id, Harvest_id, id):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            harvestform = addHarvest(request.POST)
            if harvestform.is_valid():
                createharvest = harvestform.save(commit=False)
                createharvest.user = request.user
                if Harvest.objects.exists():
                    createharvest.save()
                    return redirect("../../")
                else:
                    return render(request, "Farmer/test.html")
        else:
            harvestform = addHarvest()

        harvestcreateform = {
            'harvestform': harvestform,
        }
        return render(request, 'Farmer/CreateHarvest.html', harvestcreateform)
```

`forms.py`

```
class addHarvest(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Harvest
        fields = [
            'product',
            'years'
        ]
```

If Harvest have "2012" then `exists()` does not get object of "2012"

Comment: where's the code that fails? I don't see you using `exists()` anywhere. What code line gives an error or gives you an unexpected result?

Comment: Note that `years` is a `ForeignKey` so your default is wrong, it has to be the `id` of an existing `YearSet` row. Normally setting a default is prone to problems, because when you create the table the first time there isn't a row to point to.

Comment: also please tell us what "breaks" means for you. "I want to breaks" and "I can't breaks it" is not English.

Comment: @dirkgroten I'm so sorry in to my english and I edit my code add exists()

Comment: @dirkgroten And breaks i mean stop process.

Comment: `if Harvest.objects.exists()` means: if there is already a `Harvest` object in your database (at least one), but no specific one, so any `Harvest` object. So with your code, you will never create any `Harvest` object, assuming you start with empty database.

Comment: if you want to filter on specific attributes of `Harvest`, use `filter()`: `if Harvest.objects.filter(years=createharvest.years).exists()` for example. But if you want to avoid duplicates, you can better add `unique` constraints on the model, so your form will not be valid if the new `Harvest` is not unique.

Comment: @dirkgroten I can do it now thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to NOT create a `Harvest` when a record with the year exists, in which case you need to check if a Harvest instance with the specified year is there.

`if Harvest.objects.filter(years=int(request.POST['years']).exists()` will return `True` if there is a Harvest record with the years the same as on the form.